# Mysql Subtotal Row by Row

Tags: mysql

The table is as follows:

```
| Date       | Amount   |
|-----------------------|
| 2014-02-02 | -500     | 
| 2014-03-05 |  15      | 
| 2014-03-25 |  20      |
| 2014-04-14 |  12      |
| 2014-04-30 | -200     |
```

Is there a query that would make an output like this:

```
| Date       | Amount   |  Balance  |
|-----------------------------------|
| 2014-02-02 | -500     |   -500    |
| 2014-03-05 |  15      |   -485    |
| 2014-03-25 |  20      |   -465    |
| 2014-04-14 |  12      |   -453    |
| 2014-04-30 | -200     |   -653    |
```

I need to get the balance of every transaction. Please Help me out guys.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick :

```
 select main.Date,main.Amount,grp.balance
from @T1 main inner join (

SELECT x.Date          
     , SUM(y.Amount) balance 
  FROM
     ( 
       SELECT * FROM @T1
     ) x
  JOIN
     ( 
       SELECT * FROM @T1
     ) y
    ON y.Date <= x.Date
 GROUP 
    BY x.Date
    ) grp
    on grp.Date = main.Date
```

Comment: That works Great!!.. Thank you very much you're such a genius :)

Comment: Thanks man, I have just added amount to the query as well, so that should be the complete query for you.

Comment: Can you please vote the answer if it was helpful (by clicking the up arrow just above the tickbox)

Comment: Wish I could. But I don't have 15 reputation to upvote